# Best way to close GPSDO PLL digital loop?

Tags: oscillator, gps, pll, time

I am trying to build a GPSDO with a holdover capability of 500us/24hs (maximum drift accumulated).
The system uses a 10MHz OCXO and it is my intention to use a microcontroller (ATMega, STM or something similar) to close the loop and make some control of the loop in normal and holdover scenarios.

I have seen several GPSDO architectures like the following:
[image]
(source: https://www.egloff.eu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=241:gpsdo-software&catid=11&Itemid=114&lang=en)
Which closes the loop on HW and only when there is a holdover scenario they apply on the OCXO the last voltage read by the ADC.

But the architecture I have preliminary chosen is this:
[image]
Which closes the loop always digitally, even when there is PPS available. In normal mode, the ADC and the DAC should be "transparent", which means it emulates the HW closed loop. However, in holdover mode, the DAC should retain the voltage value which was using previously and may apply some corrections in order to compensate temperature/ageing effects on the OCXO.

If someone has a bit of experience on this field and could tell me if this approach is a good idea, I would highly appreciate it. Meanwhile, I'm starting with hw and sw development of the project.
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: I have written on this topic before; perhaps some of [these answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A11683+gps+timebase) will provide some insight.